# robot movement steps

Tags: mobile-robot

What does term "number of movement steps" mean in multi-robot exploration?.

It is a performance metric for comparing results like exploration time and energy consumed by robots during exploration.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. For example you can add a reference where you read that because it may have a different meaning from what you are expecting.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Saad Javed, but I'm afraid that it's not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and look at the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Also please *[don't add greetings](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)* to your questions. It may seem counter intuitive, but excessive politeness can itself be impolite, as giving people extra text to read, even if they ignore it, is disrespectful of their time. For specific guidelines on behaviour, see our [Code of Conduct](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/conduct).